# monaco editor - custom value completion in JSON

Tags: json, monaco-editor

I'm trying to add custom value completion in JSON configuration files.
Monaco editor has `CompletionItemProvider` extension point, but it's too generic and operates on plain text.

There is another extension point `JSONWorkerContribution` available in [vscode-json-languageservice](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-json-languageservice/blob/master/src/jsonLanguageService.ts#L137), it provides JSON-aware interface `collectValueCompletions(uri: string, location: JSONPath, propertyKey: string, result: CompletionsCollector): Thenable<any>`.

Is there any option to pass custom implementation of `JSONWorkerContribution` to the instance of Monaco Editor?